# Drupal 8 - Extend module controller

Tags: 8, panels

I want to extend PanelsIPEPageController but I have this error:

```
[Tue Mar 07 09:48:26.308720 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1170:tid 140603094411008] [client 192.168.10.155:60806] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\\zoo_ipe\\Controller\\Drupal\\panels\\panels_ipe\\Controller\\PanelsIPEPageController' not found in /home/www/dev/www/modules/zoo_ipe/src/Controller/PanelsIPEPageController.php on line 6\n', referer: http://dev.local.fr/admin/config/development/performance
```

This is my code :

modules/zoo/src/Controller/panelsIPEPageController.php

```
namespace Drupal\zoo_ipe\Controller;

use Drupal\panels\panels_ipe\Controller\PanelsIPEPageController as ControllerBase;

class PanelsIPEPageController extends ControllerBase {

  public function getBlockPlugins($panels_storage_type, $panels_storage_id) {
    echo "ici"; die();
  }

}
```

Error is on this line :

```
class PanelsIPEPageController extends ControllerBase {
```

And my zoo_ipe.routing.yml :

panels_ipe.block_plugins_zoo:

```
  path: '/admin/panels_ipe/variant/{panels_storage_type}/{panels_storage_id}/block_plugins'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\zoo_ipe\Controller\PanelsIPEPageController::getBlockPlugins'
  requirements:
    _panels_storage_access: read
    _permission: 'access panels in-place editing'
    _method: 'GET'
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Something isn't matching up - the error is on line 15 of panelsIPEPageController.php, but there weren't even 15 lines of code in the code you posted for that file.

Comment: I have removed comments for the post.

It's line 9
    class PanelsIPEPageController extends ControllerBase {

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This is new log :

`[Tue Mar 07 11:39:36.411255 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1171:tid 140603195123456] [client 192.168.10.155:62340] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\\panels\\panels_ipe\\Controller\\PanelsIPEPageController' not found in /home/www/dev/www/modules/zoo_ipe/src/Controller/PanelsIPEPageController.php on line 7\n', referer: http://dev.local.fr/admin/config/development/performance`

Comment: You should update the post to show the actual information.

Comment: Sorry. I just updated the post.

Comment: Why alias the class to something used all through Drupal core?

Comment: I want to change code for the getBlockPlugins in panels ipe module

I think solution is to extend class but I want to keep same class name.

I think this is the same :

`namespace Drupal\zoo_ipe\Controller;

use Drupal\panels\panels_ipe\Controller\PanelsIPEPageController as CBase;

class PanelsIPEPageController extends CBase {

  public function getBlockPlugins($panels_storage_type, $panels_storage_id) {
   echo "ici"; die();
  }

}`

Comment: I found the mistake.

I write use Drupal\panels\panels_ipe\Controller\PanelsIPEPageController instead of use Drupal\panels_ipe\Controller\PanelsIPEPageController

I have no more error in the log, but I still do not pass in my getBlockPlugins :(